# Codeigniter: Generating student result sheet from three tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following tables in my database. The tables `midterm` and `finalterm` contain marks of students.

[image]

Now I want to display a marks sheet of all the students in single page like following:

[image]

I know how to query in single table but I am facing problem in this case as there are three tables.

I am using Codeigniter, would you please kindly help me with what to code in my model and view file?

Thanks in advance :)

This is my Controller:

```
         $this->load->model('Mod_student');
     $data['records1']= $this->Mod_student->check1();
         $this->load->view('view_student',$data);
```

## Updated part

This is my view:

```
    <?php if(count($records1) > 0) { ?>

      <?php foreach ($records1 as $row){ ?>



   <table>
   <tr> <td><?php echo $row['StudentName']; ?></td></tr>

     <tr>

      <td><?php $midDate   =   explode(',',$row['MidDate']);
     foreach($midDate as $md)
         {
         echo $md;
         echo '<br />'  ;
         }
    ?>
         </td> 

       <td><?php $midDate   =   explode(',',$row['MidSubject']);
     foreach($midDate as $md)
         {
         echo $md;
         echo '<br />'  ;
         }
    ?>
      </td> 

       <td><?php $midDate   =   explode(',',$row['MidMarks']);
     foreach($midDate as $md)
         {
         echo $md;
         echo '<br />'  ;
         }
    ?>
       </td> 



       </tr>





     </table>




<?php  } ?>

<?php } else { echo "No Record Found";} ?>
```

I have changed my view file and now it is working fine :) But there are some problems that I am facing. If I run the above script I get the following output

[image]

If you notice my table `midterm`, you would see that the student whose `id` is 3 has got the same marks in both English and Maths. But in my output it displays mark for only one subject in the middle. Is it happening because you used `distinct` in your query? I have tried removing the distinct but then it does not show exact data.

Would you please kindly tell me how to fix the problem?

And thanks again for your help.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution for you. It will fetch a single record for each student contining all of his information. I have used here GROUP_CONCAT of mysql. Therefore, on the php end you will have to explode the value and then access it in the loop. By the way here is the query you can run it like this.

```
 $query= "select
          s.id   as SID,
          s.name as StudentName,
          (select group_concat(distinct midterm.date) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidDate,
          (select group_concat(distinct midterm.Subject) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidSubject,
          (select group_concat(midterm.marks) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidMarks,
          (select group_concat(distinct finalterm.date) from finalterm where finalterm.student_id = SID) as FinalDate,
          (select group_concat(distinct finalterm.marks) from finalterm where finalterm.student_id = SID) as FinalMarks,
          (select distinct sum(midterm.marks) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidTotal,
          (select distinct sum(finalterm.marks) from finalterm where finalterm.student_id = SID) as FinalTotal
          from students as s
          left join midterm as m on m.student_id = s.id 
          left join finalterm as f on f.student_id = s.id
          and f.subject = m.subject
          group by s.name;";

    $query  =   $this->db->query($query);
```

OR Active Record Version

```
$data   =   array(
                    's.id   as SID',
                    's.name as StudentName',
                    '(select group_concat(distinct midterm.date) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidDate',
                    '(select group_concat(distinct midterm.Subject) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidSubject',
                    '(select group_concat(midterm.marks) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidMarks',
                    '(select group_concat(distinct finalterm.date) from finalterm where finalterm.student_id = SID) as FinalDate',
                    '(select group_concat(distinct finalterm.marks) from finalterm where finalterm.student_id = SID) as FinalMarks',
                    '(select distinct sum(midterm.marks) from midterm where midterm.student_id = SID) as MidTotal',
                    '(select distinct sum(finalterm.marks)from finalterm where finalterm.student_id = SID) as FinalTotal'               
                    );
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->group_by('s.name');
    $this->db->group_by('s.name');
    $this->db->from('students as s');
    $this->db->join('midterm as m','m.student_id = s.id','left');
    $this->db->join('finalterm as f','f.student_id = s.id','left');
    $this->db->group_by('s.name');
```

With distinct keyword. Here are some instructions to use this.
1. Every group concat should be exploded to be used at the php end. Like this

```
<?php echo $row['StudentName']?>
```

And Group Concat Item form query

```
 $midDate   =   explode(',',$row['MidDate']);
 foreach($midDate as $md)
 {
 echo $md;
 echo '<br />'  ;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have tried your script but I couldn't make it work, probably there is some problems with the script in my view file. Would you please kindly take a look in the edited part of my post above. I have posted my script for Controller and view file. Thanks again.:)

Comment: Thank you very much, you just taught me a new thing (group_concat), I had no idea about it before.:) I am trying to google it for more information and examples. thanks a lot man.:)

Comment: see my edits also if there is any questions related to codeigniter activerecord please tell me i love to solve and vote me up if you think i deserve

Comment: Thanks man its now working quite perfectly other than some problems. I have mentioned about those problems above in my post, would you please kindly look at it? And of course you deserve vote up and I have already done that and I am going to mark your answer as my accepted answer. Thanks man you have been really helpful. Actually I am trying to create an accounting system and currently stuck with general ledger from journals. That is why I have posted this question to get an idea about how to do it. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It is now working perfectly. You are genius, no doubt about that :) I have one more thing to ask which is not related to this post, but still if possible please reply.. do you know any book or website that will guide me through with the mysql query to create Genereal Ledger from Journals(I am talking about financial accounting)? I am really struggling with this. Thanks :)

Comment: sorry i dont really know i am afraid i usually search the net for stuff. and yesterday i saw your question related to accounting i intedned to solve it today but i can't find it

Comment: Yes, I removed it as I thought you overlooked the question. I am going to draw a complete diagram of my database and post as a new question, hope you would kindly take a look at it also. Thanks again. :)

Comment: please check this link to my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191481/how-to-create-general-ledger-t-account-using-php-mysql    . I believe you can solve it, Thanks :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10180/discussion-between-raheel-shan-and-black-belt)