# How to create General Ledger/T-Account using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, accounting

I am trying to create a double entry financial accounting system. I have completed designing the database for it, please check this link to see the diagram of my database . http://i39.tinypic.com/juhbv6.png

I have tried a lot to develop the mysql query to produce the general ledger but I got no where close. All I have managed to do is create ledger for only one account where I have to create for unlimited account.

The query I have tried is following:

```
 $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('credit_side');
    $this->db->join('debit_side', ' debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr ');
    $this->db->join('transaction_info', 'transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr ');
    $this->db->join('accounts', 'accounts.code = credit_side.account_code ');
    $this->db->where('debit_side.account_code', '1001'); 
    $this->db->order_by('voucher_date','ASC');
```

After failing to write the mysql query which can produce the ledger for all accounts I have written down the logic to create General Ledger/T account .

Now, would you please help me with the mysql query?

Please check the database before going through the following.
Thanks in Advance :)

1. Get the `accounts.name` AS AccountHead, `accounts.code` from accounts.
2. Go to the table `debit_side` and `get debit_side.account_code`, 
   if `debit_side.account_code`=`accounts.code` then get `credit_side.account_code` AS AccountName1 (but when I will echo in php, I want to get the name instead of the code itself)  and `credit_side.amount` AS Amount1, `SUM(credit_side.amount)` AS TotalAmount1  from `credit_side` where `debit_side.transaction_id_dr`=`credit_side.transaction_id_cr`
   and `transaction_info.voucher_date` is in between date1 and date2 
   WHERE `transaction_info.transaction_id`=`debit_side.transaction_id_dr`
3. After completing the second step go to the table `credit_side` and `get credit_side.account_code`,
   if `credit_side.account_code`=`accounts.code` then get `debit_side.account_code` AS AccountName2 (but when I will echo in php, I want to get the name instead of the code itself)  and `debit_side.amount` AS Amount2, `SUM(debit_side.amount)` AS TotalAmount2  from `debit_side` where `credit_side.transaction_id_cr`=`debit_side.transaction_id_dr`
   and `transaction_info.voucher_date` is in between date1 and date2 
   WHERE `transaction_info.transaction_id`=`credit_side.transaction_id_cr`

Now in the view file I aim to have the following:

```
   <table width="200" border="0">
     <tr><td colspan="5">Account Head <?echo $AccountHead ; ?> </td> </tr>


    <tr>
           <td>Dr.</td>
           <td>amount.</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td>Cr</td>
          <td>Amount</td>

    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><?echo $AccountName1 ; ?></td>
       <td><?echo $Ammount1 ; ?></td>
      <td></td>
 <td><?echo $AccountName2 ; ?></td>
     <td><?echo $Ammount2 ; ?></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td><?echo $TotalAmount1 ; ?></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
 <td>Total  </td>
 <td><?echo $TotalAmount2 ; ?></td>

     </tr>
     </table>
```

## General Ledger Sample

[image]

Comment: I think this question is probably too localised (as well as too long). Could you edit it to narrow down the exact problem you're having? People won't download your SQL from a download site (use pastie.org instead) nor read PDFs - make it easier on your readers, and a great deal more succinct `:)`.

Comment: I am sorry,.. okay I am going to delete the unnecessary stuffs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function getDebits(){    
    $data   =   array(
                'debit_side.account_code DebitCode',
                'group_concat(distinct accounts.name) as DebitAccount',
                'group_concat(debit_side.amount) as DebitAmount',
                'group_concat(transaction_info.voucher_date) as DebitVoucherDate'
                );
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from('accounts');
    $this->db->join('credit_side','accounts.code = credit_side.account_code','left');
    $this->db->join('debit_side','debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->join('transaction_info','transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->group_by('debit_side.account_code');
    $this->db->order_by('debit_side.account_code','ASC');
    $query  =   $this->db->get();
    return  $query->result_array();
}


public  function getCredits()
{
    $data   =   array(
                'credit_side.account_code CreditCode',
                'group_concat(distinct accounts.name) as CreditAccount',
                'group_concat(credit_side.amount) as CreditAmount',
                'group_concat(transaction_info.voucher_date) as CreditVoucherDate'
                );
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from('accounts');
    $this->db->join('debit_side','accounts.code = debit_side.account_code','left');
    $this->db->join('credit_side','debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->join('transaction_info','transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->group_by('credit_side.account_code');
    $this->db->order_by('credit_side.account_code','ASC');
    $query  =   $this->db->get();
    return  $query->result_array();
}
```

Sorry for late reply but this is the perfect thing you want test before you do anything with. i wanted to create a view file for this but but it seems to be complicated and takes more time which at the moment i lake

EDITED

This solution might be racking you on the view as i have tested it How ever i have tried to combine these two queries and succeeded. The query might look like some thing complex but it is fetching the perfect results.
Here it is

```
$data   =   array(
                  'debit_side.account_code    Code',
                  'group_concat(distinct accounts.name) as DebitAccount',
                  'group_concat(debit_side.amount) as DebitAmount',
                  'group_concat(transaction_info.voucher_date) as DebitVoucherDate',
                  '(SELECT group_concat(distinct accounts.name) as CreditAccount FROM (accounts)
                    left JOIN debit_side ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code
                    left JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    left JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    group by credit_side.account_code
                    having credit_side.account_code = `Code`) as CreditAccount',
                  '(SELECT  group_concat(credit_side.amount) as CreditAmount FROM (accounts)
                     left JOIN debit_side ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code
                     left JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                     left JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                   group by credit_side.account_code
                   having credit_side.account_code = `Code`) as CreditAmount',  
                  '(SELECT  group_concat(transaction_info.voucher_date) as CreditVoucherDate FROM (accounts)
                    left JOIN debit_side ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code
                    left JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    left JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    group by credit_side.account_code
                    having credit_side.account_code = `Code`) as CreditVoucherDate'

                );
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from('accounts');
    $this->db->join('credit_side','accounts.code = credit_side.account_code','left');
    $this->db->join('debit_side','debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->join('transaction_info','transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->group_by('debit_side.account_code');
    $this->db->order_by('debit_side.account_code','ASC');
    $query  =   $this->db->get();
    return  $query->result_array();
```

Although this query works fine but here is a modified and optimized version of this query i really learned things from this query you should take a look at this too

[Strange Behaviour of Group by in Query which needs to be optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518718/strange-behaviour-of-group-by-in-query-which-needs-to-be-optimized/10533100#10533100)

Comment: thanks raheel shan, I have tried your code; the result it produces is not the general ledger. I am trying to find out the problem, I will come back with the report very soon. :) thanks :)

Comment: @  raheel shan. I have been playing with your script but couldn't make it work, so this time I have written down the logic to achieve what I am trying to achieve. I believe you can solve the problem this time and as the written logic will give you an exact idea what I have been looking for. So should I post it as a new question or edit this question? Please kindly reply. Thanks :)

Comment: ok edit this question but dont remove the previous data that might help

Comment: Raheel Shan I have updated my question, would you please kindly check it?

Comment: Can you please upload an image where there are debits and credits are with account name so that i can form it.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been helping me a lot. I have uploaded the image, please check the "General Ledger Sample" part of my post above. Thanks again.