# Combining two queries into one without using UNION ALL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following two mysql queries and I am trying to combine them into one.

Query 1:

```
$getData = $this->db->query("SELECT *,accounts.name AS DebitAccountName ,debit_side.amount AS DebitAmount
    FROM credit_side
    LEFT JOIN debit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
    LEFT JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
    LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.code = credit_side.account_code 
    WHERE debit_side.account_code='1001'");
```

Query 2:

```
 $getData = $this->db->query(SELECT *,accounts.name AS CreditAccountName,credit_side.amount AS CreditAmount
    FROM debit_side
    LEFT JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
    LEFT JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = debit_side.transaction_id_dr
    LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code 
    WHERE credit_side.account_code='1001'");
```

I have tried UNION ALL but this is actually not working in this case, The problem is when I echo `$DebitAccountName` it displays the results of `$CreditAccountName` as well, which I don't want.

I am using Codeigniter, and in my view file I aim to echo the results like this.

```
 <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>

<?php foreach ($records as $row){ ?>

<?php echo $row['DebitAccountName']; ?> 
  <?php echo $row['DebitAmount']; ?>

<?php echo $row['CreditAccountName']; ?> 
  <?php echo $row['CreditAmount']; ?>
```

Would you please kindly help me get the two queries into one?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have combined these queryies

```
        $data   =   array(
                  'debit_side.account_code    Code',
                  'group_concat(distinct accounts.name) as DebitAccount',
                  'group_concat(debit_side.amount) as DebitAmount',
                  'group_concat(transaction_info.voucher_date) as DebitVoucherDate',
                  '(SELECT group_concat(distinct accounts.name) as CreditAccount FROM (accounts)
                    left JOIN debit_side ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code
                    left JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    left JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    group by credit_side.account_code
                    having credit_side.account_code = `Code`) as CreditAccount',
                  '(SELECT  group_concat(credit_side.amount) as CreditAmount FROM (accounts)
                     left JOIN debit_side ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code
                     left JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                     left JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                   group by credit_side.account_code
                   having credit_side.account_code = `Code`) as CreditAmount',  
                  '(SELECT  group_concat(transaction_info.voucher_date) as CreditVoucherDate FROM (accounts)
                    left JOIN debit_side ON accounts.code = debit_side.account_code
                    left JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    left JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
                    group by credit_side.account_code
                    having credit_side.account_code = `Code`) as CreditVoucherDate'

                );
    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->from('accounts');
    $this->db->join('credit_side','accounts.code = credit_side.account_code','left');
    $this->db->join('debit_side','debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->join('transaction_info','transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr','left');
    $this->db->group_by('debit_side.account_code');
    $this->db->order_by('debit_side.account_code','ASC');
    $query  =   $this->db->get();
    return  $query->result_array();
```

See Edits here too

[How to create General Ledger/T-Account using PHP Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191481/how-to-create-general-ledger-t-account-using-php-mysql/10193343#10193343)

Well here is a modified and optimized version of this query thanks to @vyegorov

[Strange Behaviour of Group by in Query which needs to be optimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518718/strange-behaviour-of-group-by-in-query-which-needs-to-be-optimized/10533100#10533100)

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Its working now, though its not showing one information but I think I can handle it from here. I also have to make some adjustments in my view file. You are a terrific developer, you have helped me a lot :) thanks man.

Comment: it took me nearl three days and group by debit_side.account_code is the most important thing i found

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use SELECT from both tables (debit_side and credit_side)? Of course with all JOINs you need for each table.

Comment: Are you trying mean I should do like this->> SELECT * FROM ((query1) AND (query2))?? I have tried this but its showing error. Would you please kindly show me what you are trying to mean? Thanks :)

Comment: What if you try `SELECT *,accounts.name AS DebitAccountName ,debit_side.amount AS DebitAmount,credit_side.amount AS CreditAmount
    FROM credit_side
    LEFT JOIN debit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
    LEFT JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
    LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.code = credit_side.account_code 
    WHERE debit_side.account_code='1001'`

Comment: Thanks Temni for your reply. I have tried your code but it is showing the value of $row['DebitAccountName']; AND $row['DebitAmount']; 
 but not of $row['CreditAccountName']; AND $row['CreditAmount'];

Comment: Last try =). SELECT *,accounts.name AS DebitAccountName,accounts.name AS CreditAccountName ,debit_side.amount AS DebitAmount,credit_side.amount AS CreditAmount FROM credit_side LEFT JOIN debit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr LEFT JOIN transaction_info ON transaction_info.transaction_id = credit_side.transaction_id_cr LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.code = credit_side.account_code WHERE debit_side.account_code='1001'

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity sake, I've left out the transaction_info JOIN:

```
SELECT debacc.name AS DebitAccountName, debit_side.amount AS DebitAmount,
    credacc.name AS CreditAccountName, credit_side.amount AS CreditAmount
FROM debit_side
LEFT JOIN credit_side ON debit_side.transaction_id_dr = credit_side.transaction_id_cr
LEFT JOIN accounts credacc ON credacc.code = credit_side.account_code
LEFT JOIN accounts debacc ON debacc.code = debit_side.account_code
WHERE debit_side.account_code='1001'
```

This query references the accounts table twice, once for debit side, once for credit side. This allows you to show info from both sides of the transaction.